# How to move shape python

Tags: python, shapes

I am trying to move an octagon on python
What am I missing?
How do I make this shape move

```
bif="space.jpg"

import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

points=[(-60,20),(-60,-20),(-20,60),(20,60),(60,20),(60,-20),(20,-60),(-20,60)]
colour=(0,191,255)

pygame.init()

screen=pygame.display.set_mode((1280,800),0,32)
background=pygame.image.load(bif).convert()

for point in points:
    point[-60] += movex
    point[20] += movex

while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type==KEYDOWN:
            if event.key==K_LEFT:
                movex=-1
            elif event.key==K_RIGHT:
                movex=+1
            elif event.key==K_UP:
                movey=-1
            elif event.key==K_DOWN:
                movey=+1
        if event.type==KEYUP:
            if event.key==K_LEFT:
                movex=0
            elif event.key==K_RIGHT:
                movex=0
            elif event.key==K_UP:
                movey=0
            elif event.key==K_DOWN:
                movey=0

    x+=movex
    y+=movey

    screen.blit(background,(0,0))

    pygame.draw.polygon(screen,colour,points)

    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: you calculated new values for x and y but never used them.

Comment: Well, I guess you probably need to update the values of the x and y coordinates in you array of points.

Answer (score 0):

Right there are a couple issues with your code.

1) To be able to change the array points you need to use another data structure than a list of tuples, because tuples are immutable. So you could have a list for example like that:

```
points=[[-60,20],[-60,-20],[-20,60],[20,60],[60,20],[60,-20],[20,-60],[-20,60]]
```

2) In this loop:

```
for point in points:
    point[-60] += movex
    point[20] += movex
```

You are trying to access the -60th and 20th element of the list of points which will instantly throw an error both for index out of range and because as I explained before tuples are immutable and you are trying to change their value. What I understand from the above code is that you want to move each point with movex and movey. To do that the above for loop should be changed to this:

```
for point in points:
    point[0] += movex
    point[1] += movey
```

You also need to move the above for loop below the key events inside the main loop to make it work.

3) You need to initialize `movex` and `movey` to something before attempting to access them so outside your main loop you could simply initialize them like this:

```
movex = 0
movey = 0

while True:
    #code
```

4) At this state you don't need the `x` and `y` variables at all to move the octagon as you directly increment each point by the movex and movey variables.

With all the above changes your code should now look something like this:

```
bif="alien.png"

import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

points=[[-60,20],[-60,-20],[-20,60],[20,60],[60,20],[60,-20],[20,-60],[-20,60]]
colour=(0,191,255)

pygame.init()

screen=pygame.display.set_mode((1280,800),0,32)
background=pygame.image.load(bif).convert()

movex = 0
movey = 0

while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type==KEYDOWN:
            if event.key==K_LEFT:
                movex=-1
            elif event.key==K_RIGHT:
                movex=+1
            elif event.key==K_UP:
                movey=-1
            elif event.key==K_DOWN:
                movey=+1
        if event.type==KEYUP:
            if event.key==K_LEFT:
                movex=0
            elif event.key==K_RIGHT:
                movex=0
            elif event.key==K_UP:
                movey=0
            elif event.key==K_DOWN:
                movey=0

    for point in points:
        point[0] += movex
        point[1] += movey

    screen.blit(background,(0,0))

    pygame.draw.polygon(screen,colour,points)

    pygame.display.update()
```

And that should work pretty smoothly :)
Hope that my answer helped you!
Cheers,

Alex

Comment: Thank you so much Alex, you just made my day!